# PnP JS Add Item with FieldGeolocationValue - SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I'm trying to add an item to a list that contains a Geolocation field, I cannot find how to add a value to this field in the docs, I've tried with several ways, no success:

```
await web.lists.getByTitle('Opiniones')
.items.add({
   ...
   Location: { "__metadata": {"type": "SP.FieldGeolocationValue"}, Latitude: parseInt(req.body.lat||0), Longitude: parseInt(req.body.long||0) 
   ...
}
```

or this way:

```
await web.lists.getByTitle('Opiniones')
.items.add({
   ...
   Location: { Latitude: parseInt(req.body.lat||0), Longitude: parseInt(req.body.long||0) 
   ...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745125/how-to-post-geolocation-values-to-a-sharepoint-list-field-with-rest-api

Comment: That's how it's done with the REST api, I'm asking how to do it with PnP JS Library.

Comment: put all params other than Latitude and Longitude and try

Answer (score 1):

I tested to set location field value using PnP Js like this and it's working as expected：

```
  pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Products").items.add({
        Title: "NewLocationAdded",
        Location: {
          "__metadata": {"type": "SP.FieldGeolocationValue"},
          "Latitude": 60.2872339,
          "Longitude": 24.8516785
      }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

[image]

[image]

In your side, you could manullay set a double value to Latitude and Longitude directly like above to test if it works.